# Использование анонимного класса

Tags: java, android

```
mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
            R.string.correct_toast,
            Toast, LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
});
```

Что делает эта строка кода?

```
new View.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: Создает экземпляр View.OnClickListener. Искренне ваш Кэп

Comment: Создает экземпляр анониммного класса, реализующего интерфейс `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для метода `setOnClickListener()` аргументом должна быть указана реализация (экземпляр) интерфейса слушателя, которая будет обрабатывать событие, привязанное к объекту этим методом.

Вы можете:

1. Написать реализацию этого интерфейса отдельно, присвоив имя созданному  экземпляру и затем указав это имя в методе `setOnClickListener()`.
2. Имплементировать интерфейс в класс и реализовать только абстрактные методы интерфейса, без создания отдельного экземпляра, реализующего интерфейс (т.к. интерфейс имплементирован в класс , его экземпляр будет создан вместе с экземпляром класса).
3. Либо, как в вашем случае, реализовать анонимный экземпляр, который не будет иметь имени, так как при таком использовании он в нем не нуждается и обращения к этому экземпляру реализации интерфейса из каких-либо еще мест не планируется.
   Данный вариант ни чем не отличается от пункта 1, за исключением того, что вместо указания имени экземпляра, реализующего интерфейс где то в другом месте программы, вы в метод `setOnClickListeber()` целиком вставляете всю реализацию: начиная от выделения памяти под экземпляр и заканчивая реализацией абстрактных методов интерфейса.

В любом из этих случаев, для того, чтобы интерфейс работал, он должен быть реализован через экземпляр (абстрактная оболочка интерфейса должна получить конкретную реализацию с действиями). В Java для создания экземпляра объекта используется конструкция с служебным словом `new` в результате чего выделяется память под все это дело и создается новый экземпляр объекта - в общем то для этого и нужна непонятная вам строка.

PS: это основы ООП, если они вам непонятны, рекомендуется заканчивать писать и начинать **читать** , скажем Эккеля.