# Проблема с анонимными классами: как понимать создание объекта интерфейса?

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

Вот очень простой код:

```
item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Вроде бы все легко. А я его не совсем понимаю. Даже немного стыдно из-за этого.
В частности, не понимаю вот это выражение new ActionListener(). Здесь ведь есть и операция new и круглые скобки.. Как будто бы мы создаем объект. Но ведь нельзя создать объект интерфейса. Да и потом понятно что здесь создается анонимный класс, а не объект.
Объясните пожалуйста, почему такой странный синтаксис и что же на самом деле тут происходит?

**UPD:** Написали что этот вопрос может являться дубликат:
[Использование анонимного класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432952/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)
Но там разбирается что в принципе происходит в строе new ActionListener(){}
А я понимал, что там создается объект анонимного класса, мне было интересно почему для этого используется имя интерфейса.

Comment: *мне было интересно почему для этого используется имя интерфейса* - на этот вопрос ответ в дубликате тоже, как бы, есть.

Comment: ок, значит не понял ответ. В любом случае уже разобрался.

Comment: @pavlofff Может, вопрос и дубль, но здесь ответ более человеческий.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Когда ты создаешь новый объект, ты пишешь так:

```
new Foo(<parameters>);
```

Точка с запятой в конце важна, ты вызываешь непосредственно конструктор класса Foo.

В случае с анонимным классом ты делаешь так:

```
new ActionListener() { 
    // Тело нового класса
}
```

Обрати внимание на фигурные скобки. Это разница в синтаксисе.
Теперь по смыслу: фактически ты создаешь наследника класса и одновременно вызываешь его конструктор без параметров, дополнительно в теле реализуя необходимые тебе методы. То есть такой себе одноразовый класс-наследник.

Ты мог бы сделать так в отдельном файле:

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

А затем:

```
item.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

по смыслу было бы аналогично, но в дальнейшем ты сможешь ещё создавать объекты MyActionListener, в то время как при использовании анонимного класса ты его описал, создал объект и забыл о его описании.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! То есть получается, что имплементация тут все-таки есть, просто пропущено ключевое слово implements? Ну и имя класса не указывается. А создается  и анонимный класс, имплементирующий нужный нам интерфейс, и сразу его объект, поэтому и используется синтаксис вызова конструктора?

Comment: Да, все верно :)